# Magento search queries yielding empty results in API

Tags: magento

I have this chunk of code:

```
//to-do
public function searchVehicles($terms, $offset=1, $order='ASC')
{
    if (trim($terms) == '') {
        return array();
    }

    $query = $this->_getQuery($terms);
    $query->setStoreId(1);
    if ($query->getId()) {
        $query->setPopularity($query->getPopularity()+1);
    }
    else {
        $query->setPopularity(1);
    }
    $query->prepare();
    $query->save();

    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
    $collection->getSelect()->joinInner(
        array('search_result' => $collection->getTable('catalogsearch/result')),
        $collection->getConnection()->quoteInto(
            'search_result.product_id=e.entity_id AND search_result.query_id=?',
            $query->getId()
        ),
        array('relevance' => 'relevance')
    );
    $collection->setStore(1);

    //Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
    //Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInSearchFilterToCollection($collection);

    return $this->_listProductCollection($collection, $offset, $order);
}
```

Which is inside a Resource class and reachable via SOAP.

**Before we start**: Yes, I remember to do the cache flushing and recompiling process - I clarify because this is an usual issue to newbies like me xDDD.

**Now**: I can access such method **but it returns []**.

**SPECIAL NOTE**: `$this->_listProductCollection($collection, $offset, $order);` **WORKS** since i'm using the same method in other collections fetched from other methods in the same resource, and have no trouble at all.

Let me review the intention of my code since I'm a newbie at Magento (I'm using version 1.6.2).

1. The code is based on the CatalogSearch/ResultController controller's `indexAction()` method, and tried to learn about it.
2. An empty query will yield an empty result and will not bother the Magento search engine.
3. There's only a Store (id = 1) in the site and the search query is created like this:

   ```
   private function _getQuery($terms)
   {
       $query = Mage::getModel('catalogsearch/query')->loadByQuery($terms);
       if (!$query->getId()) {
           $query->setQueryText($terms);
       }
       return $query;
   }
   ```
4. The query increases it's popularity (I took this code from the controller. I assume this is for statistical purposes only).
5. The query is prepared (I think this means: the MySQL internal query is prepared) so I can fetch it later.
6. The query is saved - AFAIK this means that the query results are iterated and cached so a subsequent same query will only fetch the stored results instead of processing the search again.
7. At this point the query will have an ID.
8. I get the whole Product collection, and join it with the search result table. SEEMS that the results table has - at least `(queryId, matchedProductId)`. I only keep the products having IDs in the matched results, and from store 1.
9. I list the products.
10. Note that the filters are currently commented.

However, the returned list is [] (an empty list) when I hit this API entry point, althought searching in the usual search bar gives me the expected result.

**Question**: What am I missing? What did I misunderstood in the process?